# Injecting a configuration class into a constructor using Simple Injector

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

I have a class with configuration settings. So, I want to use Simple Injector for using my config class like this:

```
public class Host 
{
   private readonly ServiceConfig _config;

   public Host(ServiceConfig config)
   {
      _config = config;
   }
}
```

Can I do like this?

```
public static class IoC
{
    public static Container Container { get; set; }

    public static void Configure(Container container)
    {
       container.Register<ServiceConfig>();

        Container = container;
    }
}
```

Comment: what _is_ the question?

Comment: Are you using Autofac, Unity or other? Or just trying to make your own?

Comment: I'm using Simple Injector

Comment: Please show the code for `ServiceConfig`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should register your configuration object as a 'single instance':

```
container.RegisterInstance<ServiceConfig>(new ServiceConfig { ... });
```

Comment: Yes, it's working for me:  `container.Register( () => new ServiceConfig(), Lifestyle.Singleton);`